# Changing sent action of a bar button item

Tags: swift

Hi I'm trying to change the sent action for a bar item button called scan , I have two versions of the same app, that connects to a bluetooth sensor. When you tap the scan button it searches for sensors and list them in a table view, so you select the row with the found sensor and it get connected.
Now, the working version has the scan item's Sent Action set as scan, while the not working one has it set as unwind segue, and once you tap to the button it goes to the tableview but it won't list anything.

how do I change it from unwind segue to scan?

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSQDE.png)

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdIP1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! I was trying to connect the button straight from it, instead of doing it from the properties inspector. That must have been my mistake in the first place.